# How can I protect an old site that has no validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Scenario**:

I have a website (CATALOG.COM), without any validation request, and without source code.
Now I need to set a validation to access.

**Possibility Solution**
If I create another site with validation (START_WEB.Com), and after I redirect on CATALOG.COM, can be a good solution ?

For example:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Run_Old_WebSite()
    {            
        return Redirect("www.Catalog.com");
    }
```

Any suggestions?

p.s. I work with Asp.net, Mvc and Bootstrap

Comment: No, because you could still just completely bypass your "validation" (I'm guessing you are probably looking for authentication) by navigating to the redirect url directly.

Comment: if you have access to the `IIS` then try [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without the source code availability , You cannot validate the page.

Below is the alternate solution for this:
When any one hit the CATALOG.COM apply the 301 redirection rule to it and return it to the new site url like:     `START_WEB.Com?returnUrl=CATALOG.COM`

Then in the new site add some validation login page, authenticate it and then redirect it to the old url:  `CATALOG.COM?validated=true`

In this way you can achieve this, Here you can track the users also who are visiting to the old url site.

Comment: What's to stop me from directly opening validated=true link?

Comment: you can cross check the cookie name here, when anyone opens the link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the published files, I would copy them to my local machine, decompile the site specific assemblies using something like Jetbrains dotPeek (it's free) and re-create a new solution in Visual Studio with the decompiled sources. Depending on site size/complexity this may take a bit of time but you would at least be able to make improvements to the code,build and deploy.